# How can i click an image from the search results page

Tags: selenium, webdriver, nunit

I am writing a test in Webdriver C# with Nunit. I have a search results page loaded with a list of products with images. I want to click the 1st image in the results.

I have tried using the Xpath (I used firepath to get this value)

```cs
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "html/body/form/div[2]/div[4]/div/div[2]/p")] 
private IWebElement ProductImage_xpath {get; set; }
```

When it runs it says:

> Could not find element by XPath.

I would like to use CSS selector if possible as that is faster than finding by Xpath.

What syntax could I use to locate the image from the code snipped below?
Note: the hyperlinks are dynamic, I don't want to use the href.

```cs
public SearchResultsPage clickProduct_Image()
{            
    ProductImage_xpath.Click();
    Console.Out.WriteLine("ProductImage = " + ProductImage_xpath.Text);
    return new SearchResultsPage(Driver);
}
```

The Code snippet:

```html
<div id="main" class="nav_redesign s-left-nav-rib-redesign" data-page-construction="aui" skeleton-key="results--searchTemplate listLayout so_gb_en --left-nav--shopping-engine">
  <div id="topStatic">
    <div id="top">
      <div id="topAmabot"> </div>
      <div id="searchTemplate" class="searchTemplate listLayout so_gb_en ">
        <div id="topDynamicContent">
          <div id="rightContainerATF">
            <div id="rightResultsATF">
              <div id="widthPreserver"></div>
              <div id="centerPlus">
               <div id="rhsAjax"></div>
               <div id="resultsCol" class="">
                 <div id="centerMinus" class="">
                  <div id="atfResults" class="list results apsList">
                   <div id="result_0" class="fstRow prod celwidget" name="1780974728">
                    <div class="linePlaceholder"></div>
                    <div class="image imageContainer">
                      <a href="http://testerServer1co.uk/SpaceExplorer/dp/1780974728/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1409311161&sr=8-1&keywords=planets+1">
                      <div class="imageBox">
                        <img class="productImage cfMarker" alt="Product Details" src="http://ecx.images-test.com/images/I/51iYWWt1BqL._SL160_PIsitb-sticker-arrow-dp,TopRight,12,-18_SH30_OU02_AA160_.jpg" onload="viewCompleteImageLoaded(this, new Date().getTime(), 16, false);">
                      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xpath is very very bad choice to find element on the page =). As you said better use css selector. I don't know how your image presents on the page, but i'll write possible variants, choose the best one. So, using css selectors to find your image:

```
1. You can find any element using it's class

//will find "div class="image imageContainer""
driver.findElement(By.Css(".imageContainer"))

2. Combine searching by class and find first "a" child in that div

driver.findElement(By.css(".imageContainer > a"))

3.Find element using known attribute

driver.findElement(By.css("img[alt='Product Details']"))

4. Find element by ID

driver.findElement(By.Css("#atfResults"));
//or
driver.findElement(By.Id("atfResults"));
```

Well, it will be enough for you, i think. If you have any questions, you are welcome.